# What encryption method does the .NET FormsAuthentication.Encrypt() method use?

Tags: .net, authentication, encryption

What encryption method does the .NET FormsAuthentication.Encrypt() method use?

There's no mention in the MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is defined by the [machineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx) element:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="..." 
                decryptionKey="..." 
                validation="SHA1"
                decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: What if my machine.config does not have a machine key as you said in you reply. then which algorithm does .net use as default?.

Comment: I find no machineKey setting in my machine and local server, any idea of what algorithm is used by default in this condition?.

Comment: From the same page: `it defaults to SHA1, which uses the HMACSHA1 algorithm`