# What type of Encryption does FormsAuthentication use?

Tags: c#, encryption, forms-authentication

I recently used `FormAuthentication.Encrypt` to create a temporary token which I was passing via the query string.

Now I am wondering about the wisdom of this and looking into what type of encryption it actually uses to see if it is secure enough for passing as part of the url.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it says:

> Creates a string containing an encrypted forms-authentication ticket suitable for use in an HTTP cookie.

Does that mean it is suitable for use in a URL as well? I don't know so I went digging a bit.

In the encrypt function it calls:

```
AspNetCryptoServiceProvider.Instance.GetCryptoService(Purpose.FormsAuthentication_Ticket, CryptoServiceOptions.None).Protect(numArray1);`
```

Where `numArray1` is the ticket being encrypted.

But this is where I loose it a bit, a couple of methods later it seems to use something called `HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper` but I can't find the `HomogenizingCryptoService` anywhere?

And I haven't hear of this type of encryption?

Is this good? Bad? Strong enough to pass as part of Url?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642598/what-encryption-method-does-the-net-formsauthentication-encrypt-method-use it uses whatever is defined in the machine.config