# How to decrypt Authentication Cookie From Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, cookies

Say I have some Form's authentication Cookie:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
  "TESTTEST",
  DateTime.Now,
  DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
  false,
  String.Empty,
  FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
```

Normally in C# we can decrypt this like so:

```
var authToken = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
```

I'm creating a tool for testing an I want to decrypt the cookie on the client-side.

If my machine key is: GHFDK45sDFGSKj234 How can I decrypt the Authentication from Javascript?

Comment: First you need to know the algorithm that the forms authentication [is using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642598/what-encryption-method-does-the-net-formsauthentication-encrypt-method-use). Then you need to find a javascript library that can decrypt that algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find that, so you can specify the encryption, and it defaults to SHA1

Comment: @CallbackKid if you post that as an answer I'll mark it correct

Comment: no answers so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651618/decode-sha1-using-javascript

Comment: @VinodSrivastav  yeah that was my mistake the SHA-1 is for tampervalidation, I think the encryption is AES

Comment: @johnny5 http://stackoverflow.com/a/15125030/3057246

Comment: @VinodSrivastav Thanks that link is perfect man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know the algorithm that the forms authentication [is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642598/what-encryption-method-does-the-net-formsauthentication-encrypt-method-use?noredirect=1&lq=1). Then you need to find a javascript library that can decrypt that algorithm

Comment: Is this cookie even javascript accessible? Do we really want to have the machine keys available to a web client?

Comment: @MadMyche He says he's creating a testing tool. I doubt this will be in his production environment